# Twitter auth, how to post deferred status

Tags: twitter

I'm writing an app which provide service for clients to schedule their status updates into twitter.

So a client authorizes on my web page (with twitter OAuth), creates list of deferred statuses, set times, possibly logout.

When it is time for my service to post these updates - there is a problem: I cannot obtain access_token, because my user has already logged-out and may be not here at all and therefore cannot grant access to the app.

There are few different options to obtain the access token, is anyone can explain me which the best choice for me.

Options: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/obtaining-access-tokens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use [3-legged](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/3-legged-authorization).

When the user OAuths, your site will be sent their OAuth token.  You need to store it in a database and then use it when it is time to post the status.

The token will remain valid even if the user has logged out.